# When the iOS webrtc native library peer connection is closed, unity audiosource.Play() does not work

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, frameworks, webrtc, audio-source

I provide an iOS webrtc library for unity to use. When I close the connection, my unity AudioSource.Play() can't play sound.

Calling AudioSettings.Reset() fixes the problem, but AudioSettings.Reset() causes the UI thread to stall for 1-2 seconds.